# Laravel database backup schedule

Tags: laravel

I am trying to set up a scheduler for weekly database backup in laravel. I have created a command and filled out some data like the command itself and description, and registered it in the console kernel as well. **The issue is that the file never gets created and/or stored in storage.**

This is the part of the code where is the command:

```
public function handle()
{
    Log::info('Database backup completed.');

    $filename = 'mysite' . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') . ".gz";
    $command = "mysqldump --user=" . env('DB_USERNAME') ." --password=" . env('DB_PASSWORD') . " --host=" . env('DB_HOST') . " " . env('DB_DATABASE') . "  | gzip > " . storage_path() . "/app/backup/" . $filename;
    $returnVar = NULL;
    $output = NULL;

    exec($command, $output, $returnVar);
}
```

This is the kernel part:

```
/**
 * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $commands = [
    OtherCron::class,
    DatabaseBackupCron::class,
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param Schedule $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('othercron')->dailyAt('00:00');
     $schedule->command('database-backup:cron')->everyFiveMinutes();
}
```

**Note**: I have used "->everyFiveMinutes()" just for testing purposes :)

Comment: At first, I would recommend you use special syntax for scheduling exec commands instead wrapping it into laravel console command. Check this: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#scheduling-shell-commands

Comment: @SergeiShitikov seems like this could work, but only one question. How can I provide an array of data from schedule to the kernel?

Comment: You could use a ready-made lib for that: https://github.com/spresnac/laravel-artisan-database-helper

and then just call the command in the scheduler as you like ;)

Comment: @Sead Silajdzic what do you mean? I would do it just like something like this:
$schedule->exec'(mysqldump -u '. config('database.mysql.username'). ' -p"'. config('database.mysql.password'). '" config('database.mysql.database').  > config('database.mysql.database').'.backup.sql')->daily();

Not sure about passing password argument. Just play a bit with this.

Comment: @Paladin 'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Have you ever encountered this issue?

Comment: Sure, than the path to the binary is not in your path environment. Either you add it to your path or you set the full path to the binary in the command. My packages handles both options 

Comment: @Paladin I have set it up, but when I put it as an option in artisan command Artisan::call(db:backup MySQL path -D) then it returns me that db:backup command does not exist.

Comment: @Paladin please put this reply as a comment so I can check it for some points. It is the right solution (in my case).

Comment: You are welcome, github stars are always nice to see too 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a ready-made lib for that:
github.com/spresnac/laravel-artisan-database-helper
and then just call the command in the scheduler as you like ;)

You can also set the full path to your mysqldump binary, if it's not in your path ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, it is working for me, the only difference is in Kernel, I wrote like this.

```
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\DatabaseBackUp'
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
      //some other commands
        $schedule->command('database:backup')->weekly();
    }
```

now the moment I run `php artisan database:backup` a file with the extension .zp created in the storage folder

[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
php artisan make:command DatabaseBackUp
```

Use this command make databasebackup file.

```
app/Console/Commands/DatabaseBackUp.php
<?php
  
namespace App\Console\Commands;
  
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Carbon\Carbon;
   
class DatabaseBackUp extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'database:backup';
  
    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';
  
    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
  
    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $filename = "backup-" . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') . ".gz";
  
        $command = "mysqldump --user=" . env('DB_USERNAME') ." --password=" . env('DB_PASSWORD') . " --host=" . env('DB_HOST') . " " . env('DB_DATABASE') . "  | gzip > " . storage_path() . "/app/backup/" . $filename;
  
        $returnVar = NULL;
        $output  = NULL;
  
        exec($command, $output, $returnVar);
    }
}
```

In this step, we need to create "backup" folder in your storage folder. you must have to create "backup" on following path:

```
storage/app/backup
```

Now, in this step, we need to schedule our created command. so let's update kernel file as like bellow:

```
app/Console/Kernel.php
<?php
  
namespace App\Console;
  
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
  
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\DatabaseBackUp'
    ];
  
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('database:backup')->daily();
    }
  
    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');
  
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

you can check following command to getting database backup with this command:

```
php artisan database:backup
```

t will create one backup file on your backup folder. you can check there.

Now, we are ready to setup cron on our server.

At last you can manage this command on scheduling task, you have to add a single entry to your server’s crontab file:

Run following command:

```
crontab -e
```

Comment: Sorry but you have literally copy-pasted the online tutorial :) I have followed it and here I am :) But thanks anyways.